# org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate.hbm.xml not found

Tags: hibernate

Help me to resolve this issue .it is not connecting to the data base and ia m using wamp server as database

[File hierarchy][1]

>

```html
public boolean login() {

    try{
      SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      Query query=session.createQuery("from Login where username=:username and password=:password");
      query.setString("username", username);
      query.setString("password", password);
      List list=query.list();

      System.out.println("list size"+list.size());

       if(list.size()==1){
       return true;
       }else{
       return false;
               }
         }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Log  file and i am using glass fish server

```html
HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Info:   HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN:   HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Info:   HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: hibernate.hbm.xml
WARN:   HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN:   HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (2) : The content of element type "class" is incomplete, it must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
Info:   org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:488)
```

hiberanate config file :hibernate.config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsfformdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <!--  <property name="password" /> 
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> --> 
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!--<mapping class="Login.Login"></mapping>-->
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

-->

Hiberanet mapping file:hibernate.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Login.Login" table="login1"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (2) : The content of element type **"class" is incomplete**, it must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,**(id|composite-id)**,discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".

The `class` mapping in `hibernate.hbm.xml` needs an `id` (or `composite-id`) defined, as well as the properties in the class, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "Login.Login" table = "login1">

      <id name = "username" type = "string" column = "username">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>

      <property name = "password" column = "password" type = "string"/>
      ...
      other properties...
      ...
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```